# override SelectAll in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

Is there anyway, I can copy the text inside `UITextView` to the clipboard when the user chooses Select All without waiting for Copy command from the user?

In other words, is it possible to make a `-selectAll` method like the following?

```
-(BOOL)selectAll
{
    //custom code to copy the text
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What's with the weird hybrid objc/c method/function there?  args are denoted by a colon, (type), and a local var name.  Empty parenthesis with no local var name are not allowed (with a var name, they should default to id, but the compiler will complain at you)\

Comment: @CodaFi its pseudo-code, don't have to worry about syntax.

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed That's statement is completely ridiculous.  He can code in whatever language he likes, but it has to actually ***be*** a language if he expects help.  Syntax is important, and if you don't believe me, try compiling this gibberish, the compiler will complain.  It looks a little more like C or javascript now.  Shall I retag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UITextView and override `canPerformAction` where you can call your own clipboard function if selectAll is chosen

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
    {
        [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = self.text;
        return YES;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, this will only copy the text to the clipboard, but how can I override the selectAll method.

Comment: It gives me: Use of undeclared identifier 'textView'

Comment: Use self.text since it is a UITextView subclass now.